# How to perform Drag & Drop functionality in Selenium WebDriver where we need to drag files from local machine to a web portal?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

> How to perform Drag & Drop functionality in Selenium WebDriver where
>   we need to drag files from local machine to a web portal?

Comment: Doesn't that web-portal have an interface for entering the file name? Provide the URL, and I might be able to show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for a method by which we can drag and drop file directly to webpage.

One of my friends just told me that we cannot do it but we can do this within webpage using `Robot()` class. Below is the code:

```
package com;
import java.awt.Robot; 
import java.awt.event.InputEvent; 

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 

public class Robott { 

    @Test 
    public void DragnDrop() throws Exception { 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.get("http://gmail.com"); 
        Robot r = new Robot(); 
        Thread.sleep(4000); 
        r.mouseMove(400, 350); 
        r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); 
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        r.mouseMove(500, 350); 
        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); 
    } 
}
```

By using `Robot()` class we can do mouse and keyboard actions, so it may work here.

Comment: Well It may work for a particular machine. But test would be failed with a different screen resolution. Other than that its a good try actually

Answer (score 1):

You can try Selenium Advanced Interactions approach.

for example:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
    .moveToElement(otherElement)
    .release(otherElement)
    .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

for more information, check [Advanced Selenium Interactions guide by luke semerau](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions)